# Bootstrap 3 - how place an image on a dropdown button with caret on same line

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm a bootstrap/html wimp.  I'm trying to get a Bootstrap dropdown with a facebook icon, and a caret next to it on the same line:

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group"> 
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="facebookDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
        <img src="/assets/facebook-sq.png" width="20" height="20">
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-form" aria-labelledby="facebookDropdown">
        ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

The caret is presenting itself below the facebook icon as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rpiI.jpg).

From what I gather it is because there is a break after the img tag.  I've tried all sorts of variations using "display='inline-block'" as some had suggested, to no avail.  Can any wizards help me?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose its just a sizing issue. Tweak the width, and height until you are comfortable.

However... If it is icon images you require, may I suggest the use of icon fonts instead of images; you'll find these way less painful, and more convenient. My most favorite is [FontAwesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) but there's an [icon font repository](http://weloveiconfonts.com) with plenty of collections for you to chose from.

Comment: FA does look like it might work for my purposes, so I'll check it out. But I don't think it is a sizing issue, the button width will expand based on its contents.